# react + backbone + react-router, fetching models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react and backbone models in my app. To communicate with each other I use higher order components (https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750).

Let say I have a backbone model:

```
class Item extends Backbone.Model {
  defaults() {
    return {
      id: null,
      name: 'item',
      subItems: [],
      link: null
    };
  }

  // This is sample API response to GET /item/1
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'item1',
    link: '/item/1',
    subItems: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'item2',
      link: '/item/2', 
      subItems: []
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'item3',
      link: '/item/3', 
      subItems: []
    }]
  }

  // This is sample API response to GET /item/2
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'item2',
    link: '/item/2', 
    subItems: []
  }
}
```

and react component:

```
class ItemComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  onClickLink(link, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.transitionTo(link);
  }

  render() {
    const itemData = this.props.data.toJSON();
    const itemNodes = itemData.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <li><a href='' onClick={this.onClickLink.bind(this, item.link)}>{item.name}</a></li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <span>{itemData.name}</span>
        <ul>{itemNodes}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ItemComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

and I have my higher order component

```
const item = new Item();
const NewComponent = connectToModel(ItemComponent, item);
```

where

```
function connectToModel(Component, model) {
  class ComponentConnection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.state = {
        data: model
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      model.on('add remove change', this.onModelChange.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      model.off(null, null, this.onModelChange.bind(this));
    }

    onModelChange() {
      this.setState({
        data: model 
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component
          {...this.state}
          {...this.props}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

my routes:

```
const Routes = (
    <Route handler={App} path="/">
      <Route name="item" path="item/:id" handler={Item} />
    </Route>
);
```

My questions:

1. How can I call the API to fetch data before rendering when user requesting url `/item/1` so instead of `const item = new Item();` I would call something like `const item = new Item({id: 1});`.
2. When user click on a subitem, react router will get him to e.g `/item/2`, but then how I can tell to my react component that the route param has change therefore fetch new model override my current one and render new data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 100% how it would work with stores, but the way I've been doing it is to use statics on the component to say which APIs need to be called, then fetch that data before the route actually renders the component and pass the resulting data as a prop to it. Because every transition will fire the router, it will always grab the relevent data as long as your API is based on data from the query or param.

This repo was huge in helping me get off the ground... [Mega React Router Demo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-mega-demo)